# How do i get the formula for this rate of change problem?

Tags: calculus

Scenario: a car is sitting in the road at 0mph, when he decides to make his trip 500mi straight, he hit's the pedal and starts the road at 15mph, he holds his foot down on the pedal the whole time, and each hour that passes by his mph is increased by 15mph, but... the car's limit is 60mph, so how long did he take to reach 500miles?

** what i tried:

15miph 1st hour
30miph 2nd hour
45miph 3d hour
60miph 4th hour

he traveled 150miles in 4 hours
500 - 150 = 350 miles left, @ constant speed of 60mph

350/60 = 5.83 hours + 4hrs
= his trip took 9.83 hours to travel 500miles

im not interested in the solution, im interested in a formula/equation that will get to the answer quickly, instead of mapping it manually, what if his initial mph was 10mph instead of 15? what if the car's limit is 80mph instead of 60? i'd have to manually calculate this and it's too inefficient, so help me out here, what formula can work given 15mph, 60mi, 500mi? to equal 9.83hr?

Comment: Honestly I'm not sure why you're getting *so* many downvotes and close votes, but I do agree that you should reformat your question a bit. I would try to summarize a bit more, perhaps only state one question at the end. Perhaps also use MathJax, you can find a reference [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), although it's not necessary. Overall, I would just restructure your post from the ground up... it just seems a little thrown together and difficult to follow.

Comment: Why don't you just consider each given number as a variable? Call the distance as $d$,the highest speed as $h$, the initial mph as $i$, and the acceleration per hour as $a$? Then after each hour, the speed of the car increases by $a$, so it will go from hour to hour like $i,i+a,i+2a,...$ until you hit $h$. Unless you've already reached, the remaining distance is covered in speed $h$. Now you  can find the time on each stretch, so the total time.This is a routine exercise, we'd prefer it if you do it yourself because this site is not allowed to spoonfeed answers.